# Static Mixer Types

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics

I'm studying static mixers design and found out that there're many types of element shapes, such as KMS, KMX, SMV, SMX, etc. is that name some abbreviation, or it's just what is it? If yes, can anyone help me find out its abbreviation? If not, can anyone tell me what it means? Somehow, it's hard to find my answer on google, so I just put my question here. I'll put the complete list here.

- General K Static Mixer: KMS, KMX, HEV.
- General G Static Mixer: SMV, SMX, SMXL, SMR, KVM, KHT, SMF, KFBE.
- General R Static Mixer: ISG, LPD, LLPD.

Comment: Why not check the manufacturer for the names? Seems a sensible move.

Comment: as far as I can tell, at least some of these are trademarked https://www.askiagmbh.de/downloads/Mixing_and_Reaction_Technology_e_23270640.pdf don't get hung up on terminology, just try to understand the different working principles. If you ever actually need a static mixer, the application engineer of a manufacturer is your friend.